# Could not find 'flat-ui.css' in any of your source paths while generating Flat UI Pro in rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am integrating licensed version of flat-ui-pro with my Rails app.
For this, I am using 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails' gem

My environments are:-
OS - Windows7 32-bit 
Ruby - 1.9.3p327
Rails - 4.0.0
twitter-bootstrap-rails - 2.2.8
jquery-ui-rails - 4.0.5
designmodo-flatuipro-rails - 1.1.4.2

I have generated "**bootstrap_and_overrides.css**" file by bootstrap generator at location "app/assets/stylesheets/". I am not using ".less" files for bootstrap.

I am also **not getting** `Cannot detect twitter-bootstrap-rails install` error 
and `Invalid Flat UI Pro directory` error while running the flatUI generating command. It means I am inside the right FlatUI directory.

When I run the flat-ui-pro generate command `rails g flatuipro:install ./FlatUI/HTML/UI/Flat-UI-Pro-1.1.4`, It is throwing a error

> Could not find "./FlatUI/HTML/UI/Flat-UI-Pro-1.1.4/css/flat-ui.css" in any of yo
>   ur source paths. Your current source paths are:
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.1.4.2/lib/gener
>   ators/flatuipro/install/templates

I am getting the same error while passing the FlatUI directory containing PSD and HTML both.

I am not understanding why generator can not recognizing `flat-ui.css` in the right directory.

I used differ version of `gem "designmodo-flatuipro-rails", "~> 1.2.2.0.branch"` with the other version of FlatUI-Pro directory (1.2.2) but also getting the same error.

This is tree of FlatUiPro directory:-
[image]

Please reply with good suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting stuck very much, I found the solution.

I was hitting command in cmd-prompt:-

```
rails g flatuipro:install ./FlatUI/HTML/UI/Flat-UI-Pro-1.1.4
```

It will work with Mac/Ubuntu OS as creator of flatui-gem explained in the issue created on github <<[Link of Github Issue](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails/issues/20)>>

**In Windows, it is mandatory to put the flatui directory out of the project folder.**
For example:-
My FlatUIPro directory saved in "D:" drive, so my command will be

> `rails g flatuipro:install D:/FlatUI`

or

> `rails g flatuipro:install D:/FlatUI/HTML/UI/Flat-UI-Pro-1.1.4`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your relative-path to the Flat-UI Pro Directory to "absolute" in the rails "generate" command, seems to work only for absolute paths!

Comment: thanks for answering. But this is not relative path or absolute path issue. I answered the solution. Please check it & comment if any issue found with that.

Comment: Looking at your own solution, what you have done is "actually" change your relative path to "absolute path" by beginning with the drive! So my answer is correct and deserves to be "ticked" :-)

Answer (score -1):

Please check your Flat UI Pro directory... you really are missing demo.css for some reason. Try re-downloading the Flat UI Pro assets from designmodo

Comment: Thanks but I have no need to use demo.css and also not generating demo.css. Please read my question again.